# How can I copy specific parts of different files in different directories and save them to open in R?

Tags: r, linux, unix, vim

I have several files with the same name: data.out
and they are in different folders.

I need to get some data on each of these files, save them in file (.csv) to then open in R later. The data that I will need in each of these files are matrices of 7x7.
like that:

```
***** Estimates of covariance matrix   ***************************************
      
 Matrix 
   1     0.8
   2     5.6       0.2
   3     3.6       5.1       1.3
   4     1.2       6.6       1.2       5.6
   5     2.7      -3.2      -8.6       3.1       7.2
   6     5.1       9.3       5.8       2.4       4.2       6.2
   7     1.5      -2.6      -3.1       9.2       8.1       8.7
         1.1
```

```
**** Estimates of residual matrix  ***********************************
 Covariance matrix
   1     2.1
   2     4.1       3.1
   3     1.3       5.6       1.4
   4     4.5       2.1       8.5       1.1
   5     5.1      -5.1      -6.6       5.2       4.1
   6     2.4       4.7       4.2       3.1      -1.2       1.7
   7     1.2       9.2       3.1       4.5       8.1       1.3
         3.9
```

```
**** Estimates of correlation matrix  ***********************************
 Correlation matrix
   1     1
   2     4.1       1
   3     1.3       5.6       1
   4     4.5       2.1       8.5       1
   5     5.1      -5.1      -6.6       5.2       1
   6     2.4       4.7       4.2       3.1      -1.2       1
   7     1.2       9.2       3.1       4.5       8.1       1.3
         3.9
```

I was wondering if vim can help me to do what I would like to but can't figure it out. I first thought to use line number as an index but they are not the same in each file.
In short, I want to get these matrices from each file (data.out) in each directory (different names). Then, save them as .csv files to open in R.

Is that I way to do that without being copy and paste manually? Is vim or other text editor or even R can help me to do this faster?
thanks

Comment: You can give R a directory or list of directories and use it to read the files (i.e. using `read.table` or something from readr or zoo package etc) and manipulate their contents (i.e. using parsers or even plain regex). Then you can save them as csv (i.e. using `write.csv`). Not sure where and how vim plays into that, but R could certainly be used for such a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but you can append to a register by using uppercase letters.
example:

- in the first file, visually select the desired text. *Copy* to register 'a': `"ay`
- in the following files, visually select the desired text. *Append* to the same register: `"Ay`
- in the destination file, *paste* from said register: `"ap`

You can also copy/append the other ways you know from Vim. E.g.: Append the following 5 lines to register 'a': `4"Ayj`, or append from within braces to register 'a': `"Ayi}`